# VSCode errors when editing .tsx files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When editing .tsx files in VSCode I keep having errors.
Those errors only affect the editor, the code compiles fine and the compiler does not complain about anything.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/foF8D.png]

How can I remove these errors and warnings?

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "strict": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,

        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,

        "target": "es5",
        "outDir": "out",
        "declaration": true,
        "sourceMap": true,

        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "allowJs": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

        "jsx": "preserve",
        "noEmit": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "incremental": true,

        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["./src/*"],
            "@/public/*": ["./public/*"]
        }
    },
    "exclude": ["./out/**/*", "./node_modules/**/*", "**/*.cy.ts"],
    "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

Comment: Try calling npm install

Comment: @znat may i ask what did you do to fix the above error? am facing a similar issue

Answer (score -1):

Another (preferred) option would be fixing the problem :)

The error is telling you unreachable code is detected, so make the code reachable or remove it / comment it temporarily since it is not doing anything.

```
const add = (a: number, b: number) => {
  return a + b;
  // code never gets here since a value is already returned from the function
  const otherValue = a + 5; // unreachable code detected
}
```

```
const add = (a: number, b: number) => {
  throw new Error("Something went wrong");
  return a + b; // same here
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. The return section is for the HTML/React/Next part

Comment: @Pierrick I am explaining the error he is getting with an example, the best thing to do is fixing the issue instead of ignoring the error. The fact the code is unreachable is because it is below the return scope of the function component.